# JQuery scroll won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used the [this](http://blog.alaabadran.com/2009/03/26/scroll-window-smoothly-in-jquery/) script to but when i put it in to my website it wont work.

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<span id="title">Sidtitel</span>
 <span id="menu">
<span>-</span>
<a onclick="Home()">Hem</a>
<span>-</span>
<a onclick="About()">Om sidan</a>
<span>-</span>
<a href="#tavling">Tävlingar</a>
<span>-</span>
<a href="#doantion">Donation</a>
<span>-</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Skriv in sök!" id="search-input">
<input type="button" value="Sök" id="search-button">
</span>
<div id="content">
<div id="title">Vad kommer att hända här ?</div>
<div id="text">
Här på sidan kommer jag lägga ut tävlingar där man gör en bra<br>
sak och ni som joinar kan vinna lite fina priser.<br><br>
Sen kan ni donera en slant så jag kan köpa in lite priser och
tävla ut till er.<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="om">
ssss
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html {
font-size: 16px;
}
body {
font-size: 62.5%; /* 10px = 1em */
margin: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
#header , #om { 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient( bottom, #000 0%,#111 100%);
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
}
#header , #menu { padding-left: 20px; }
#header #title {
color: #fff;
font-size: 6em;
font-family: Oswald;
}
#menu { 
padding-left: 25px;
}
#menu a , #menu span {
color: #fff;
font-size: 3em;
font-family: Oswald;
text-decoration: none;
padding-right: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}
#menu a:hover { color: #c4112c; }
#content #title {
color: #c4112c;
font-size: 5em;
margin-top: 200px;
}
#content #text {
width: 50%;
text-align: left;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left:  auto;
font-size: 4em;
font-family: Oswald;
color: #fff;
}
```

JS:

```
function about(){
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop: $("#om").offset().top
}, 800);
}
```

Why is the javascript code not working for me ?
I've tried to put javscript in the `header`-tag and 
the `body`and also in an different file but it still won't work

Comment: Did you put it in the `<head></head>` within `<script></script>` tags?

Comment: You are trying to call `About()` with a capital `A` whereas you are defining a function named `about`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your page should look like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(about);

function about(){
   $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#om").offset().top
      }, 800);
}
</script>
<style>
html {
font-size: 16px;
}
body {
font-size: 62.5%; /* 10px = 1em */
margin: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
}
#header , #om { 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient( bottom, #000 0%,#111 100%);
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
}
#header , #menu { padding-left: 20px; }
#header #title {
color: #fff;
font-size: 6em;
font-family: Oswald;
}
#menu { 
padding-left: 25px;
}
#menu a , #menu span {
color: #fff;
font-size: 3em;
font-family: Oswald;
text-decoration: none;
padding-right: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
}
#menu a:hover { color: #c4112c; }
#content #title {
color: #c4112c;
font-size: 5em;
margin-top: 200px;
}
#content #text {
width: 50%;
text-align: left;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left:  auto;
font-size: 4em;
font-family: Oswald;
color: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<span id="title">Sidtitel</span>
 <span id="menu">
<span>-</span>
<a onclick="Home()">Hem</a>
<span>-</span>
<a onclick="About()">Om sidan</a>
<span>-</span>
<a href="#tavling">Tävlingar</a>
<span>-</span>
<a href="#doantion">Donation</a>
<span>-</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="Skriv in sök!" id="search-input">
<input type="button" value="Sök" id="search-button">
</span>
<div id="content">
<div id="title">Vad kommer att hända här ?</div>
<div id="text">
Här på sidan kommer jag lägga ut tävlingar där man gör en bra<br>
sak och ni som joinar kan vinna lite fina priser.<br><br>
Sen kan ni donera en slant så jag kan köpa in lite priser och
tävla ut till er.<br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="om">
ssss
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Insted of using separate function for every anchor use script below and put it just before the `</body>` tag

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#menu a').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top + 'px' }, 800, 'linear');
    });
  });
</script>
```

of course to get this to work you must give id's to your divisions same as anchor href attributes and include jQuery library in the `head` section of your document e.g.

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

and if you want script for scroll to top button

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#scroll-top').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '0' }, 800, 'linear');
    });
  });
</script>
```

anyway here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6xq6R/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: I have to ask: how do you create the fiddle button? Thanks